# Is there an open source soulutoin to view and edit WFDB file for EKG?

Tags: web-applications

I want to view and edit my WFDB files locally on my machine. [Lightwave](https://physionet.org/lightwave/) does the physionet format dataset. But I have my dataset and I don't want to publish it. I want to develop the same features and capabilities on my own and utilize them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4627786/pdf/nihms582734.pdf) which describes LightWAVE, recently-developed open-source software for viewing ECGs and other physiologic waveforms and associated annotations. It supports efficient interactive creation and modification of annotations, capabilities that are essential for building new collections of physiologic signals and time series for research.

The LightWAVE server runs as a CGI application within a web server. The web server collects user requests and forwards them to the lightwave server. The lightwave server parses the requests, obtains the requested data from local storage from a data repository such as physionet, construct appropriate responses, and passed them back to the webserver.

[Here is the repository](https://github.com/gilbertz/ligthwave) for this CGI application.